# How to accept mixin as argument in jade?

Tags: pug

I want accept mixin as argument for mixin. Here is code.

```
mixin inside
   ul
     li One
     li Two

mixin test(content)
   .wrapper
      #{content}
```

Now I'm calling mixin:

```
+test(+inside)
```

But result is NaN. Whats wrong? At all is it possible to accept mixin as argument in mixin?

Answer (score 0):

Jade does not generate pre renderings, to do what you want to do. What you can do is this

```
mixin inside
   ul
     li One
     li Two

mixin test()
   .wrapper
      block

+test()
    +inside()
```

Get that

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```